# SCSS support in Visual Studio 2013 a bit patchy?

Tags: css, sass, visual-studio-2013

I'm currently trying to get the Foundation framework integrated in a Visual Studio 2013 (Update 2 RC) environment, particularly the SCSS files. Very basic operations in SCSS seem to work well, but trying to do anything more complex seems to cause issues.

As an example, I tried inputting in the following:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}


$grid-width: 1200;
$grid-cells: 12;
$cell-padding: 5;
$cell-size: $grid-width / $grid-cells - ($cell-padding * 2);

.container {    
}

.grid {
    padding: 0 #{$cell-padding}px;
}

.grid-1 {
    width: #{$cell-size}px;
    @extend .grid;
}

.grid-2 {
    width: #{$cell-size * 2}px;
    @extend .grid;
}

.grid-3 {
    width: #{$cell-size * 3}px;
    @extend .grid;
}

.grid-4 {
    width: #{$cell-size * 4}px;
    @extend .grid;
}
```

The expected css file is created, but it is not added to the Visual Studio project, and the SCSS split view (Which I'm assuming was introduced in Update 2?) doesn't seem to want to work either. The foundation code has similar results.

I've tried using SassyStudio and Web Workbench, but got the same result - I'm not too clear how these interact now that SCSS support is native.

Are there any extensions that can be used to get SCSS support working properly, or any settings I've missed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I ask how could you generate the css file?

Comment: Can I second @AndrasToth question? My understanding is that the VS2013Update 2 support is just for editing and not compiling...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that's correct - I realized it wasn't actually Visual Studio doing the compiling, but Web Essentials which I had installed. I think they've fixed whatever issue I was having since then.